# Dominating Term between 2^logn and n^(5/2)

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

lets say in order to compute Big-O of these two functions and take log both sides fx<=c.gx log(2^logn) + log(n^(5/2)) <= log(n^(5/2)) which is log n + log n <= log n it satisfies for equals if any one function taken out from left side log n = log n. but not for less than condition. so in short can any of them be Dominating Term interchangeably.?

Comment: This is more suited to math.SE than to SO, surely?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the base of the logarithm. Call it `a`:

[image]

So if

[image]

then

[image]

and vice versa.